# ESP8266 geeting back to loop

Tags: esp8266

The most of the following code ist from @Juraj https://github.com/jandrassy/lab/blob/master/ConfigurationAP/ConfigurationAP.ino

I change it a littel bit. My Probelm now ist, I do not know, how I get back to `loop()` from `configAP()`

It works well, if the ssid and the password are already saved

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssidh = "ESP-Accesspoint";
const char* password = "12345678";

// Wir setzen den Webserver auf Port 80
WiFiServer configWebServer(80);

// Eine Variable um den HTTP Request zu speichern
String header;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);



  WiFi.begin(); // use SSID and password stored by SDK. please comment out to test the Configuration AP

  // waiting for connection to remembered  Wifi network
  Serial.println("Waiting for connection to WiFi");
  WiFi.waitForConnectResult();

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Could not connect to WiFi. Starting configuration AP...");
    configAP();
    
  } else if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    //seite();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP Adresse: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    configWebServer.begin();   
  }else{
    Serial.println("whaaat");
    }

}

void configAP() {

  WiFiServer configWebServer(80);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA); // starts the default AP (factory default or setup as persistent)
  WiFi.softAP(ssidh, password);
  
  Serial.print("Connect your computer to the WiFi network ");

  Serial.print(WiFi.softAPSSID());

  Serial.println();
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("and enter http://");
  Serial.print(ip);
  Serial.println(" in a Web browser");

  configWebServer.begin();

  while (true) {

    WiFiClient client = configWebServer.available();
    if (client) {
      char line[64];
      int l = client.readBytesUntil('\n', line, sizeof(line));
      line[l] = 0;
      client.find((char*) "\r\n\r\n");
      if (strncmp_P(line, PSTR("POST"), strlen("POST")) == 0) {
        l = client.readBytes(line, sizeof(line));
        line[l] = 0;

        // parse the parameters sent by the html form
        const char* delims = "=&";
        strtok(line, delims);
        const char* ssid = strtok(NULL, delims);
        strtok(NULL, delims);
        const char* pass = strtok(NULL, delims);

        // send a response before attemting to connect to the WiFi network
        // because it will reset the SoftAP and disconnect the client station
        client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
        client.println(F("Connection: close"));
        client.println(F("Refresh: 10")); // send a request after 10 seconds
        client.println();
        client.println(F("<html><body><h3>Configuration AP</h3><br>connecting...</body></html>"));
        client.stop();

        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        WiFi.persistent(true);
        WiFi.setAutoConnect(true);
        WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
        WiFi.waitForConnectResult();

        // configuration continues with the next request

      } else {

        client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
        client.println(F("Connection: close"));
        client.println();
        client.println(F("<html><body><h3>Configuration AP</h3><br>"));
        client.println(F("<html><body><h3>IP Adresse:</h3><br>"));
        client.println(F("<html><body><h3>WiFi.localIP()</h3><br>"));

        int status = WiFi.status();
        if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {
          client.println(F("Connection successful. Ending AP."));
          delay(1000); // to let the SDK finish the communication
          Serial.println("Connection successful. Ending AP.");
          configWebServer.stop();
          WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);          
          
        } else {
          client.println(F("<form action='/' method='POST'>WiFi connection failed. Enter valid parameters, please.<br><br>"));
          client.println(F("SSID:<br><input type='text' name='i'><br>"));
          client.println(F("Password:<br><input type='password' name='p'><br><br>"));
          client.println(F("<input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>"));
          client.println(F("<Funktion 2 <a href=\"?pin=FUNCTION2ON\"><button>einschalten</button>"));
        }
        client.println(F("</body></html>"));
        client.stop();


      }
    }
    
  }

}


void loop() {
 
   
   WiFiClient client = configWebServer.available();   // Hört auf Anfragen von Clients

  if (client) {                             // Falls sich ein neuer Client verbindet,
    Serial.println("Neuer Client.");          // Ausgabe auf den seriellen Monitor
    String currentLine = "";                // erstelle einen String mit den eingehenden Daten vom Client
    while (client.connected()) {            // wiederholen so lange der Client verbunden ist
      if (client.available()) {             // Fall ein Byte zum lesen da ist,
        char c = client.read();             // lese das Byte, und dann
        Serial.write(c);                    // gebe es auf dem seriellen Monitor aus
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // wenn das Byte eine Neue-Zeile Char ist
          // wenn die aktuelle Zeile leer ist, kamen 2 in folge.
          // dies ist das Ende der HTTP-Anfrage vom Client, also senden wir eine Antwort:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP-Header fangen immer mit einem Response-Code an (z.B. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // gefolgt vom Content-Type damit der Client weiss was folgt, gefolgt von einer Leerzeile:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();
            
            // Hier wird nun die HTML Seite angezeigt:
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");
            // Es folgen der CSS-Code um die Ein/Aus Buttons zu gestalten
            // Hier können Sie die Hintergrundfarge (background-color) und Schriftgröße (font-size) anpassen
            client.println("<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}");
            client.println(".button { background-color: #333344; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px;");
            client.println("text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}");
            client.println(".button2 {background-color: #888899;}</style></head>");
            
            // Webseiten-Überschrift
           client.println("<body><h1>ESP8266 Web Server</h1>");
            
          
            client.println("</body></html>");
            
            // Die HTTP-Antwort wird mit einer Leerzeile beendet
            client.println();
            // und wir verlassen mit einem break die Schleife
            break;
          } else { // falls eine neue Zeile kommt, lösche die aktuelle Zeile
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // wenn etwas kommt was kein Zeilenumbruch ist,
          currentLine += c;      // füge es am Ende von currentLine an
        }
      }
    }
    // Die Header-Variable für den nächsten Durchlauf löschen
    header = "";
    // Die Verbindung schließen
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client getrennt.");
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

The Programm should ends to `loop()` in both cases, I mean, if you have to `configAP()` or not.
please comment out  `WiFi.begin();` at the beginning to test the Configuration AP

Comment: sorry, something is missing :-). add `return;` after `WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);`

Comment: i still have the same problem, it the loop() is a HTML-site I want to reach, with and without WiFi.begin(); @Juraj

Comment: you server is missing begin(). it is not good to name two different variables with the same name (configWebServer).

Comment: ok thanks. what about using two differents servers like WiFiServer and ESP8266WebServer? I want to add a button in the same ConfigAP-Page, that leds to another HTML-page @Juraj